# Relative import of module in parent directory

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

I want to be able to test a python class from a testscript located in a subfolder. My project structure is as follows:

```
importTest
    __init__.py
    testFolder
        testScript.py
    tobeimported.py
```

The content of tobeimported.py is:

```
class ToBeImported:
    def __init__(self):
        self.print('Created!')
```

the content of my testScript.py is:

```
from ...importTest import tobeimported

def runTest():
    item = tobeimported.ToBeImported()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTest()
```

When I run testScript.py, I get the error:

```
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

But importTest should be known as a package right? Because it has the `__init__.py` file?

How else can I import my ToBeImported class in my testscript?

I'm running python 3.9.5

Comment: you can add `from .tobeimported import ToBeImported` in your `__init__.py` file and use `from importTest import ToBeImported`

Comment: @BijayRegmi: No, this does not work. If I try this, running testScript.py it says: 'No module named importTest. Also, this would mean that `__init__.py` would have to change based on the usage of each import. From the documentation I understood the file needs to be empty...

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Sorry for my late reply... I was running it as python3 -m importTest/testFolder/testScript.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here

- there is no `__init__.py` file in testFolder so this is not a python package as far as python is concerned
- the testScript.py is run directly from its folder. This makes python think that the top level package is testFolder so "no known parent package"

You should add the init file then run the code from the parent folder of importTest as `python -m importTest.testFolder.testScript`

Comment: Thank you so much! I never knew you could run parts of a package like this. This actually works!